# Is there a term for enjoying or liking the feeling of guilt

Tags: emotion

Obviously not sociopathy - or anything like that.

I just wondered if there was a term for enjoying the sensations of guilt  :)

EDIT can you go on - and say something about the differences between fear and guilt :) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a term specifically for pleasurable guilt.

However, depending on whom you ask, there's a couple ways we can talk about this feeling.

1. If we assume that guilt can only be experienced as negative, then we might describe pleasurable guilt as pleasure *about* guilt (i.e., a positive meta-emotional experience of guilt; for a review on meta-emotions, see [Mendonca, 2013](http://emr.sagepub.com/content/5/4/390.short)).  In other words, you experience a sense of pleasure in response to, and perhaps alongside, your emotion of negative guilt.
2. If we take a psychological constructivist view of emotions ([Condon, Wilson-Mendenhall, & Barrett, 2014](https://pccondon.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/ch4_condon_et_al_2014_hps.pdf)), then we can hypothesize that even prototypically negative emotions can be experienced as positive (e.g., positive fear, or conversely, negative happiness; see also [Wilson-Mendenhall, Barrett, & Barsalou, 2014](http://www.affective-science.org/pubs/2014/wilson-mendenhall-soc-cog-aff-neuro-2014.pdf)). So guilt isn't *necessarily* negative, even though our prototypical conceptualization of guilt is that it's negative.  That is to say that guilt is not made up of a specific and consistent set of experiences, behaviors, and cognitions. Instead, it's a heterogeneous category that can include negative or positive experiences--depending on how the individual constructs his or her affective experience.  The photo below (taken from [Condon et al., 2014](https://pccondon.files.wordpress.com/2014/01/ch4_condon_et_al_2014_hps.pdf)) shows how fear might be conceptualized as either negative or positive--and perhaps you can extrapolate from there how guilt might be similar.

[image]

By the way, the fruit category is meant to show a continuum of typical-atypical fruit examples (orange-olive), which perhaps helps to clarify the idea of typical-atypical fear (and guilt).

EDIT: To be clear, fear tends to be conceptualized as a negative emotion involving anticipation of a negative event in the future (e.g., a snake will bite me).  Guilt tends to be conceptualized as a negative emotion about a negative past event for which you feel personally responsible.  In this case, I'm using fear to describe the continuum of typical vs. atypical emotions, but note that guilt will have a different continuum.

Comment: yeah i get it, like sensation seeking about guilt rather than fear ??

Comment: oh BTW i pretty much HATE (all) sensations of fear

Comment: @user3293056 Perhaps, e.g., feeling positive guilt about spending more money than you should have on something you've wanted since you were a child. In general, it's more difficult to come up with instances of positive guilt (vs. negative) because we don't typically think about guilt as positive.

Comment: the chance to change, the ability to take on new responsibility ? i dunno, i ...

Comment: "guilty pleasures" ?? maybe i'm mis labelling the emotion ? shame is a horrid little emotion, guilt seems to open up new possibilities, both intellectual and actional ...?

Comment: pretty much did answer my question, i think! would be interested in anything more i.e. the interface between 1 and 2, but it's not so important :)

Comment: @user3293056 It's possible that you could be "mislabeling" the emotion, but language in general tends to be imprecise for abstract concepts like emotions.  In general, though, there's still a lot more research to be done on emotion concepts and labels, so for now, a lot of your questions may not be easily answerable.

Comment: The term "Guilty pleasures" is interesting because it points to the fact that we often feel guilty because we do something that that is pleasurable: We eat the cake even though we know that it is wrong because it conflicts with our dietary goals. This is a classic self-regulatory conflict. However in some situations, pleasure may even be tied to breaking rules and a behavior might be all the more desirable exactly because it is a taboo (think of the "allure of the forbidden"). Maybe this is the kind of situation that you were thinking of.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexithymia